# Counting the top 10 most frequent words per row

Tags: python, pandas

I have the sample dataset like this:

```
"Author", "Normal_Tokenized"  
x       , ["I","go","to","war","I",..]  
y       , ["me","you","and","us",..]
z       , ["let","us","do","our","best",..]
```

I want a dataframe reporting the 10 most frequent words and the counts (frequencies) for each author:

```
"x_text", "x_count", "y_text", "y_count", "z_text", "z_count"  
go ,        1000   ,  come   ,  120     , let     , 12
```

and so on ...

I attempted with the following snippet, but it just take the **last author values** instead of all authors values.

This code actually return the 10 most common **word** the author has been used in his **novel**

```
df_words = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(
    data={'Author': [row['Author'] for _ in row['Normal_Tokenized']], 'Normal_Tokenized': row['Normal_Tokenized']})
    for idx, row in df.iterrows()], ignore_index=True)
df_words = df_words[~df_words['Normal_Tokenized'].isin(stop_words)]

def authorCommonWords(numWords):
    for author in authors:
        authorWords = df_words[df_words['Author'] == author].groupby('Normal_Tokenized').size().reset_index().rename(
            columns={0: 'Count'})
        authorWords.sort_values('Count', inplace=True)
        df = pd.DataFrame(authorWords[-numWords:])
    df.to_csv("common_word.csv", header=False,mode='a', encoding='utf-8',
                  index=False)
    return authorWords[-numWords:]

authorCommonWords(10)
```

There are about 130000 samples for each author. The example get the 10 word that is most repeated word in this 130000 sample. I want this 10 words in separated column for each author.

Comment: probably better that we see your incoming and out-going DF. understand that you'll need to use `apply` with NLP here but you can probably rid your self of some of the looping here for better methods.

Comment: @billhuang thanks, done, would you please check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`np.unique(return_counts=True)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) seems to be what you're looking for.

### Data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Author": ["x", "y", "z"],
    "Normal_Tokenized": [["I","go","to","war","I"],
                         ["me","you","and","us"],
                         ["let","us","do","our","best"]]
})
```

### Code

```
n_top = 6  # count top n

df_want = pd.DataFrame(index=range(n_top))
for au, ls in df.itertuples(index=False, name=None):
    words, freqs = np.unique(ls, return_counts=True)
    len_words = len(words)
    if len_words >= n_top:
        df_want[f"{au}_text"] = words[:n_top]
        df_want[f"{au}_count"] = freqs[:n_top]
    else:  # too few distinct words
        df_want[f"{au}_text"] = [words[i] if i < len_words else "" for i in range(n_top)]
        df_want[f"{au}_count"] = [freqs[i] if i < len_words else 0 for i in range(n_top)]
```

### Result

```
print(df_want)
  x_text  x_count y_text  y_count z_text  z_count
0      I        2    and        1   best        1
1     go        1     me        1     do        1
2     to        1     us        1    let        1
3    war        1    you        1    our        1
4               0               0     us        1
5               0               0               0
```

Comment: thank you very much, that's perfect, but in the case that the n_top is more than data length, it face with ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
error, for example  here if the n_top changes to 6, we have this error, do you have any idea for it? @billhuang

Comment: Just fill the shortage of words with dummy values (text="" and freq=0). I have updated the answer.